# Fetching json api using react ( useeffect )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hellooo,

This is my first time using React. I want to fetch some data in json format and list it out in my page. The code below is not working.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function DataFetching() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({ hits: [] });
  //const [query, setQuery] = useState("redux");

  useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios("url");
      setUsers(result.data);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hellooooo</p>
      <ul>
        {users.hits.map((user) => (
          <li key={user.id}>{user.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DataFetching;
```

Comment: You would need to call `fetchData()` within your `useEffect` handler. That or just remove the extra function and call `axios` directly

Comment: When you say it is not working what do you mean? Is the response data from axios not available or you are getting some kind of error

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri OP isn't calling `fetchData` anywhere so the request is never made

Comment: When I used the above useEffect function I am getting the fikkiwing error. ```Uncaught TypeError: users.hits is undefined```

Comment: @JithinAji sounds like the response data isn't an object with a `hits` array but only you would be able to see what it actually is. Use your browser's dev tools to check the response data format in the _Network_ panel

Comment: seems like the response is JSON. Not sure if i checked in the right way I have attached screenshot.

Comment: The response from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` is an array, not an object and certainly not one with a `hits` property.

Comment: Thank you I have removed the hit and now it is showing the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Issue

1. `useEffect` hook callbacks are 100% synchronous, they can't be asynchronous (i.e. declared `async`) at all. This also implicitly returns a Promise and messes with the effect cleanup functionality.
2. Your code *never* calls the `fetchData` function, so nothing is really updated.
3. You stomp your state shape and place the result array at the root state level instead of in an object under the `hits` key.

## Solution

1. Remove the `async` keyword from the effect callback.
2. Invoke `fetchData` in the effect callback body.
3. Update state correctly.

Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await axios("url");
      setUsers({ hits: result.data });
    } catch(error) {
      // handle any GET request or response handling errors
    }
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

[image: Edit priceless-dew-qbhtu]

[image]

Comment: Excellent point about the `useEffect` return value. I totally forgot about cleanup.

Comment: Point (1) is a little weirdly put – of course the effect function can do asynchronous things, it just can't be `async`, since it'd make it implicitly return a Promise.

Comment: Hi thank you but I am not sure why I am getting an error stating ``` Uncaught TypeError: users.hits is undefined ```.

Comment: @JithinAji Your initial state is valid, i.e. `users === { hits: [] }` is true, but you then stomp over the state and it's no longer an object with a `hits` property, but rather it's the array you want, i.e. `users === [......]`, so `user.hits` is no longer defined.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got the result. I know I asked a silly question but thanks for the effort and please excuse me because this is my first time using react.

Comment: I corrected it using. ``` const [users, setUsers] = useState([]); ``` and ``` users && users.map((user) => <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>)} ```

Comment: @AKX Not really sure what point you are trying to make, I didn't say the `useEffect` callback *couldn't* do asynchronous things, but that the callback itself can't be asynchronous. I did update to expressly call out the use of `async` keyword in the issues even though I felt it was already clear enough in context with the solution. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Yeah, the point was that a function can be just as asynchronous being `async` or non-`async`: `async function x() { return 1 };` <=> `function x() { return new Promise(resolve => resolve(1)); }`